# How to disable copy and paste of particular words in JTextPane?

Tags: java, swing, jtextpane

I am using a `JTextPane`  in my project, where i add some tags through code like **[PKG MEDIA]** etc.
I want to restrict user to copy and paste them in `JTextPane`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should override `Writer` used in your `EditorKit` to skip some `Element's` content.

To prevent paste you can add a `DocumentFilter` in simplest case but in some cases paste directly changes `Document's` structure so you should override `Reader` which creates the structures.

Comment: can you provide me a short example for this??

Answer (score 0):

As hint work with `MouseEvent` and `KeyEvent` and restrict text selection using mouse and key press event of **`CTRL+V'**

Or you can also use : `textPane.setTransferHandler(null);`

see [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#setTransferHandler%28javax.swing.TransferHandler%29)